# Is it possible to install JBoss Fuse 6.3 on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jboss, jbossfuse

I have gone through the JBoss FUSE guide in [official guide](https://access.redhat.com/articles/310603) but I could not see any details regarding capabilities of install FUSE in Linux server. Have any one try this before? I have not seen any document regarding this, Appropriate if some experienced person provide feedback about this.

Is it possible to install the FUSE in Linux server for example Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS ? If it's possible is there any reference document guideline ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's possible to run the FUSE on linux without any issue. Only thing is it is required to install JDK and its better to have maven installed in your PC as well.(Note that path variable needed to be updated after install JDK and maven). If you haven't install please go through following guide lines.

01) [Install JDK in linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)

02) [Install maven in linux](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-ubuntu/)

After you installed those two then you need to download the relevant zip file from JBoss Fuse official site. Then extract the zip file in to desired location. (This location can be any place you want to install in folder structure)

Open the command line and go to bin folder on extracted folder.

then Type following command and press enter

**./fuse**

As show on below image

[image]

Then you will see similar interface to below(Usual fuse loading interface ).

[image]

Since there is not much dificulties on this I don't think there will be any documentation regarding this. I believe this steps will help you to setup JBoss Fuse in linux environment.

Comment: I was able to follow your guide and install as you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Maven is not strictly required to run JBoss Fuse.

Comment: Yes Alessandro you are correct but maven is usually used in most of cases. I have updated the answer and thanks for the feedback.